# Facebook application is only accessible by admin account

Tags: php, facebook

I developed a Facebook application in PHP. It was working fine.

Suddenly it stopped working for other users. When anybody is trying to access my Facebook application, it taking us to page https://www.facebook.com/4oh4.php and giving error "Page you requested was not found."

But same time if I am login, and I access my application, then it is working fine. I tried a lot to change the Facebook settings but nothing worked for me. There are three admins for my application.

Answer (score 3):

Check the `Sandbox Mode` on Basic settings. If it is `Enabled`, users who doesn't have Administrators, Developers or Testers role can't access to see your application.